# Let $V$ be a vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation,show that the two following statements are equivalent:

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation,show that the two following statements are equivalent:

1. The intersection of $\text{ker(T)}$ and $\text{Im(T)}$ is the subspace $\left\{0\right\}$ of $V$.
2. If $T(T( \alpha))=0_V \implies T(\alpha)=0_V$

---

I don't know how to show $1 \implies 2$.

$2 \implies 1$

Let $x \in \text{ker(T)} \cap \text{Im(T)}$,then $T(x)=0_V$ since $x$ is in the kernel of $T$,and for some $\alpha \in V:T(\alpha)=x$ since $x$ is in the range of $T$,so $0_V=T(x)=T(T(\alpha))$ which by the assumption implies that $T(\alpha)=0_V$ and since $T(\alpha)=x$ so we have that $x=0_V$.

I would like to know how to prove the other direction.

Comment: If $T(T\alpha)=0$, then $T\alpha$ is in $\ker T \cap \operatorname{im} T$.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\;\ker T\cap\text{Im}\,T=\{0\}\;$ , then

$$T(Tv)=0\implies Tv\in\ker T\,\; \text{. But trivially}\;\;Tv\in\text{Im}\,T\,,\,\,\text{so}$$

$$\;\;Tv\in\ker T\cap\text{Im}\,T=\{0\}\implies Tv=0$$